# I don't know why the result is not my have thought

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code. What I want to do is to show the detail(the last 3 rows at every section) when I did select one of the first row in all sections.

The var People is a Set type and its value is [] default and when one row was selected, it would append the current section to this Set and then when we return numberOfRows, we can depend on the People Set and decide which Section should be show only one row and which should be 4 rows.

But the result is whichever row I selected the numberOfRowsInSection is always 1.

Anybody can tell me Why it came this?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{


    if Peoples.isEmpty {
        return 1
    }
    else{
        if Peoples.contains(section) {
            return 4
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }

    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    TV.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if Peoples == []{
        Peoples.insert(indexPath.section)
    }
    else {
        if Peoples.contains(indexPath.section){
            Peoples.remove(indexPath.section)
        }
        else {
            Peoples.insert(indexPath.section)
        }
    }

    println("\(Peoples)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay,Nobody can help me but I have fixed this problem.Because I forgot to reloadData when I didSelectAtindexPath.

This is my worked code updated.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{


    if Peoples.isEmpty {
        return 1
    }
    else{
        if Peoples.contains(section) {
            return 4
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }

    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    TV.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if Peoples == []{
        Peoples.insert(indexPath.section)
    }
    else {
        if Peoples.contains(indexPath.section){
            Peoples.remove(indexPath.section)
        }
        else {
            Peoples.insert(indexPath.section)
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    println("\(Peoples)")
}
```